# I have a table format. I want to convert it to html

Tags: css, html

I am not much familiar with html design.
I am trying to get a html table like in given image. anybody have mind to help me,then please help. [image]

i started with some code.but not completed.please help
HTML

```
<html>
<body >
    <table border=1  width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2 align="center">
                Cost Analysis Report
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                Purchase
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                Sales
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's a lot of table generators online, here's one that would definitely help: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables.

Comment: And what is your question/problem? You already use `colspan`, in your example, so what is the problem using this in the large table?

Comment: `<table><tr><td colspan=23></td></tr><tr><td colspan=10></td><td colspan=10></td><td colspan=3></td></tr><tr><td></td>..* 23...</tr>`

Comment: @AlonEitan   <style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>  this helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the structure. Feel free to customize the design, all the color and value of every cell.

```
<table border=1  width="100%">
<tr>
  <td colspan="23"><center>Cost Analysis</center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="10"><center>Purchase</center></td>
  <td colspan="10"><center>Sales</center></td>
  <td colspan="3"><center>Tax</center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><center>1</center></td>
  <td><center>2</center></td>
  <td><center>3</center></td>
  <td><center>4</center></td>
  <td><center>5</center></td>
  <td><center>6</center></td>
  <td><center>7</center></td>
  <td><center>8</center></td>
  <td><center>9</center></td>
  <td><center>10</center></td>
  <td><center>11</center></td>
  <td><center>12</center></td>
  <td><center>13</center></td>
  <td><center>14</center></td>
  <td><center>15</center></td>
  <td><center>16</center></td>
  <td><center>17</center></td>
  <td><center>18</center></td>
  <td><center>19</center></td>
  <td><center>20</center></td>
  <td><center>21</center></td>
  <td><center>22</center></td>
  <td><center>23</center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><center>1</center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><center>1</center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><center>1</center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><center>1</center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><center>1</center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
  <td><center> </center></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: how the divisions can make the feel of lines?

Comment: You mean the color of the border? or the width?

Comment: <style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style> helped

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if work to you.

```html
    <table border=1  width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan=24 align="center">
                Cost Analysis Report
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=8 align="center">
                Purchase
            </td>
            <td colspan=8 align="center">
                Sales
            </td>
            <td colspan=8 align="center">
                Tax
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                1
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                1
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                1
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                1
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                1
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                1
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                1
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                1
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                2
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                2
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                2
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                2
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                2
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                2
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                2
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                2
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                3
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                3
            </td>
             <td align="center">
                3
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   <html>
   <body >
   <table border=1  width="100%">
   <thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="23" align="center">
            Cost Analysis Report
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="10" align="center">
            Purchase
        </th>
        <th colspan="10" align="center">
            Sales
        </th>
       <th colspan="3" align="center">
            Tax
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            id
        </td>
        <td align="center">

        </td>
         <td align="center">

         </td>
         <!--just continue-->
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can that border change like lines?

Comment: yes, use css <style>table td, table th{ border: solid 2px #000; }</style>

Comment: <style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style> helped